# vuejs - v-model doesn't update class property

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem with form and v-model that doesn't update my class's property

To make it quick here is really basic sample of what isn't going as I expect

```html
<input placeholder="Title" 
  v-model="title"
  type="text">
<button @click="send">send</button>
```

```js
@Component
export default class Home extends Vue {
  public title = ''

  send = async(): void => {
    console.log(this.title)
  }
}
```

The console.log prints the default property value (empty string) and is not updated when I type something in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `title` value is reactive and update by user input. According to vue class component docs you should not use arrow function in class component when you want to access `this`:

> If you define an arrow function as a class property and access this in it, it will not work. This is because this is just a proxy object to the Vue instance when initializing class properties

So this will be work and the correct value logged in console:

```
@Component
export default class Home extends Vue {
  public title = ''

  send(): void {
    console.log(this.title)
  }
}
```

For further details visit [this page](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/caveats.html#this-value-in-property-initializer).